# Using FactoryMethod pattern

Tags: java, factory

I have two separate entities:

```
public enum Rule implements Validatable, StringRepresentable{ 
     //...
}
```

and

```
public inteface Filter extends Validatable, StringRepresentable{
    //...
}
```

Where

```
public inteface Validatable{
    public GenericValidator getValidator();
}
```

and

```
public interface StringRepresentable{
    public String getStringRepresentation();
}
```

`GenericValidator` is an abstract class having a number of subclasses I would not like users to access directly. How should I handle those things better?

I don't understand when it's better to create a class like

```
public class ValidatorFactory{
    public Validator getRuleValidator(Rule r){ ... }
    public Validator getFilterValidator(Filter f){ ... }
}
```

instead of implementing the `Validatable` interface as I shown earlier.

Couldn't someone explain how can I make a right decision? What potentiall circumstances requires implementing `FactoryMethod` a bad decision and when it would be really good?

UPD:

```
public interface Validator{
    public ErrorCode validate();
}

public abstract class GenericValidator implements Validator{
   //...
}
```

The `ErrorCode` class encapsulates the result of the validation (`null` if valiadtion's completed succsfully).

Comment: If you have issues such as your `GenericValidator` subclasses, using a `ValidatorFactory` should work for you as you just want the appropriate validator for your service, right? Also, when you say "I would not like users to access directly", how do you mean?

Comment: @ha9u63ar In fact, yes. I just need the validator for the service. And I have a dillema: creating the factory or implementing the interface.

Comment: @ha9u63ar__how do you mean__ I mean the final user should only know about the GenericFactory class and its method `validate()` that's going to be overriden in subclasses. That's why I'm thinking about incapsulation the subclasses and their instantiation.

Comment: @st-antario  Interfaces are useful when you have multiple classes (but totally unrelated) are trying to implement some common behaviour. But using abstract classes, you segregate a group of related classes to implement (or improve/extend) the behaviour. Also, abstract class has got the so called inheritence thing (kind of) whereas using interface doesn't directly implement the inheritence (the whole "isa" and "hasa" business).

Comment: There is no GenericFactory class in your question and no validate() method.

Comment: @macias Do you think that's really important in that question? I thought the purpose of GenericValidator would be clear from itts name.

Comment: I am just trying to understand, what are you trying to achieve. There are many different types and no, this is not obvious how they are connected together. Is GenericValidator implementing Validator? Is Validator even an interface? Is your goal hiding the details of choosing concrete Validators implementation? I think you need to try to describe your goal more clearly.

Comment: @ha9u63ar Of course, GenericValidator is a quite abstract concept and hoidng to be used in many places in the project. So, interface would be beteer here?

Comment: @macias __Is your goal hiding the details of choosing concrete Validators implementation__ Exactly.

Comment: @macias IU've added some explanation.

Comment: @St.Antario      You have to remember that you can have both abstract and non-abstract methods in your `GenericValidator` class. Any of it's subclasses must implement all the abstract methods or will become abstract classes themselves. In this way, you can choose which functionality you want your users to be accessing directly from `GenericValidator` or it's subclasses. Does this make sense?

Comment: @ha9u63ar The only thing the user may have access to is the invocation the `validate()` method on subclasses. For instance, the user get an instance of `Filter` from a web-page and now they want the instance to be a valid. They just call `new ValidatorFactory().getFilterValidator()` and invoke the `validate()` method on it.

Comment: And how would be Validatable connected with it? Anyway, I think you are missunderstanding the concept of interfaces or something else here, not quite sure what exactly. If you would like to have a utility that allow you to easily create an instance of this Validator type hiding details about how this instance is created or which concrete implementation is chosen - use Factory pattern. I can only say this, fairly I don't understand the idea with "implementing Validatable interface".

Comment: @macias Well, any entity implementing the `Validatable` interface is going to have to define a concrete `Validator` to validate itself. Doesn't that sounf like a bad design?

Comment: Ok, that now starts to fit all together:)

Comment: @macias But in that case, if the enitity is null  I'll get NPE when try to get the Validator. It's not good....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Single Responsibility Principle**

Construction of Validator is one responsibility, Filter or Rule probably carries another one. This means we should split it and usually we do so encapsulating instantiation logic in a Factory pattern.

Also note that implementing Validatable means being a ValidatorFactory. My answer would be - combine both solutions:

```
public class FilterImpl implements Filter {
    private final Validator validator;

    public FilterImpl(Validator validator) {
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    @Override
    public getValidator() {
         return this.validator;
    }

    //...
}

public class FilterFactory {
    private final ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = new ValidatorFactory();

    public Filter createFilter() {
        return new FilterImpl(valdatorFactory.createFilterValidator());
    }
}
```

This is called **Dependency Injection.**

Comment: Imagine the situation when we have a method, say `public void method(Filter f)` and we need to get the validor of the parameter within its body. What if we passed null as the parameter? We'll get NPE then. Do you deliberately not respect this case?

Comment: Just secure the null pointer, that's it. if (f == null) { //your decision what to do}. I don't really get your concern. You sometimes need to pass parameters, all the time you need to make sure they are not null...

Comment: As far as I could understand your solution, we provide a specific Validator implementation through a constructor. I just should say that we're using Spring IoC, so can perform dependency injections easily. Should we really use it here?

Comment: In general, it's still not clear to me about making a decision of using a `Factory` or a combined solution like you provided... What actually confuses me is this: If we used `ValidatorFactory` we could create the validator in such a way so we are not going to have to perfom __not null checking__ as you mentioned in the comment. We just return the `Validator` from the factory method and perform validation on it. The thing is I try to avoid `if-else` logic everywhere it's possible, because I think it makes a program hard to understand.

Answer (score 3):

I use this pattern in two major cases:

A) Construction of the object isn't trivial - I don't trust the users of the API to do it correctly

B) There are more implementations and I want to choose the right one myself.

In both these cases I want to hide implementations simply because the user won't know which one to use and/or doesn't know how to construct it properly.

Always aim for simplicity and ease-of-use for your user. Ask yourself these questions:

1. Is the API easy to understand?
2. Is the API easy/fun to use?
3. Is it foolproof? (I have to try quite hard to misuse it)

Comment: The internals of the API are not easy to understand that's why I want to incapsulate it.

Comment: Then Factory method is a very nice way to encapsulate instance construction.

Comment: But what if I have 1000 completely separated entities and any of them needs to be validated. Then my Factory will contain 1000 factory methods? Isn't that a bad design?

Comment: I don't know your case but usually you can split it into more APIs and provide completely new way of working with it each new API best tailored to what it does.

Comment: @St.Antario Adding a method for each of your 1000 cases is not making use of the factory, it rather should be one method containing logic to choose an implementation for the arguments passed.

Comment: @macias So, if we would like to use a factory we should declare the number of the validator factories each of which relates to a specific hierarchy?

Answer (score 3):

Validator interface can look like this:

```
public interface Validator {
   public int validate();
}
```

Filter interface can look like this:

```
public interface Filter {
  public String getParameters();   // some related methods..
  public int currentLength();
  ....
}
```

Rule interface:

```
public interface Rule {
  public String getRule();
}
```

FilterValidator can look like this:

```
public class FilterValidator implements Validator{

private Filter f;

public FilterValidator(Filter f){
    this.f = f;
}

@Override
public int validate() {
    // validate f and return errorcode
    String params = f.getParameters();
    int strLength = f.currentLength();
    .....

    return 0;
 }

}
```

Creating a factory is better to hide the internal logic of validators.

```
public class ValidatorFactory {

public Validator getRuleValidator(Rule r){
    return null;
}

public Validator getFilterValidator(Filter f){
    FilterValidator fv = new FilterValidator(f);
    return fv;
}
}
```

Now client will invoke this factoy like this:

```
public class ClientDemo {

  private class MyFilter implements Filter{

    private String filterInput;
    public MyFilter(String input){
        this.filterInput = input;
    }

    @Override
    public String getParameters() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int currentLength() {
        return this.filterInput.length();
    }

}

    public void testValidators(){

      ValidatorFactory factory = new ValidatorFactory();
      Validator v = factory.getFilterValidator(new MyFilter("filter string goes here..."));
      v.validate();
     }
 }
}
```

Through the interfaces Rule, Filter you can enforce the behavior you desire from client. Then client can get instances from the factory and pass the rule/filter instances to it for validation.